# DATETIME comparisons?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to switch from using UNIX timestamps to `DATETIME` columns in MySQL and am having a little trouble finding the correct way to make comparisons between dates.

I tried using the `+` and `-` operators to compare two `DATETIME`s and the results don't make any sense to me.

For example:

**1.**

```
SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

Outputs

```
2014-07-06 19:19:13 | 2014-07-06 18:19:13
```

These

```
SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP() - DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP() - (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Both output `10000`. This number doesn't make sense to me, but then it gets more confusing as this:

```
SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP()-DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
```

Outputs `1`. Why is that? What does that number represent?

**2.**

[The manual page for date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) shows `DATE_ADD()` and `DATE_SUB()` can be used to add and subtract intervals from dates, but I don't see any functions in the manual that correspond to the great than and less than operators, so how would I check to see if the current date is greater than some other date?

I tried using the `<` and `>` operators and they seem to work, but I can't seem to find anything on this in the manual and want to make *sure* it's OK to use these operators like this:

```
SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP() > DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

---

Can anyone demystify `DATETIME` comparisons in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found this out myself, but here's a quick example that shows you how it works.

@GordonLinoff's answer is neither here nor there, because your question isn't really about the format returned from `utc_timestamp()`.  What you're really asking is what format does MySQL return when you use numeric operands `+` and `-` on timestamps.

I tend to agree with you that the documentation is a bit fuzzy on the topic.  But this is what I found.  You can build this view yourself to see the example in simpler terms.

```
create view cbhview as
select utc_timestamp() as nowtime,
       utc_timestamp() - interval 1 hour as thentime,
       date_sub(utc_timestamp(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) as thentime2,
       date_sub(utc_timestamp(),INTERVAL 1 SECOND) as justthentime;

select nowtime, thentime, thentime2, justthentime,
       nowtime-thentime,
       nowtime-justthentime,
       thentime-thentime2
from   cbhview;

+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| nowtime             | thentime            | thentime2           | justthentime        | nowtime-thentime | nowtime-justthentime | thentime-thentime2 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| 2014-07-06 20:22:58 | 2014-07-06 19:22:58 | 2014-07-06 19:22:58 | 2014-07-06 20:22:57 |            10000 |                    1 |                  0 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

- `100000` represents `1h 00min 00second`
- `1` represents `1second`
- `0` represents no difference between the two

In short, unless you know exactly what you're doing and exactly what you're trying to achieve, don't use numeric operands on `date` and `timestamp` datatypes.  Keep to the functions that have been designed for the purpose `date_add()` and `date_sub()`.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up a lot. So using `+` and `-` on datetime values doesn't produced a desirable result, but what about greater/less than comparisons? Is using `<` and `>` the appropriate way to check if one datetime value is greater/less than another?

Comment: @Nate Yes, of course you can use `>`, `<=` and other operators to compare.  It would make filtering your data rather complicated if you couldn't do that. `select * from cbhview where nowtime<thentime;`

Comment: @Nate I just saw what you're trying to do. Yes, you can also put logical comparators in the `select` statement, but this doesn't filter (as it would in the `where` part of the statement). So again, be careful that you know what you want. In the `select` statement, a logical comparitor gives you a `true/false` (actually `1/0`) response. `select nowtime<thentime from cbhview;`.  SO hint: don't ask 2 questions in 1!  Create a separate questions if you want to split them up.

Answer (score 4):

To quote the documentation about `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`:

> Returns the current UTC date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format, depending on whether the function
>   is used in a string or numeric context.

Because the value is being used in the context of a number, it is treated as a number, which is the behavior that you see.